# Equivalent of Firebug for Thunderbird

Tags: email, dom, firebug, thunderbird, chromebug

When I build a newsletter and send it to myself as a test, I would like to be able to analyze the resulting HTML in my email client (Thunderbird).

Is there a tool similar to Firebug but for Thunderbird? I found one called "DOM Inspector" but it is pretty weak and hard to use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chromebug works on XUL applications generally and I recently tried it on Thunderbird. This is the program we use to debug Firebug.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug_User_Guide

You want the most recent 1.7X.0a build.

jjb

Comment: Would it be possible to amplify this a bit?  I followed the chromebug instructions, installed 1.7.2 and then started Thunderbird with the -chromebug flag.  It started, but the "OK, Let me at it!" button does nothing, and the key menus (e.g. "filter") are inactive.  This is TB 1.6.1 on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know is Venkman, the Javascript Debugger (http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/).

I actually do like the DOM Inspector, the "Edit -> Select Element by Click" menu helps a lot with finding information about a particular part of the chrome.